# Vue : command not found after installing @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I don't know why isn't working for me. I opened powershell as administrator and run `npm install -g @vue/cli`. I have done uninstalling vue-cli and restalling again doesn't work. Here is my error

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g @vue/cli
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
C:\Users\Lin Aung\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\Lin Aung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js

> protobufjs@6.8.8 postinstall C:\Users\Lin Aung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall C:\Users\Lin Aung\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @vue/cli@3.5.0
added 680 packages from 509 contributors in 172.749s
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> vue
vue : The term 'vue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ vue
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (vue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `%APPDATA%\npm` to the PATH fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

install using sudo

sudo yarn global add @vue/cli

Comment: The issue is on windows.

Answer (score 0):

### At windows:

First step: %path%;%appdata%\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\User.npm-global;C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\

in environment variable

second step: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

install yarn or npm

third step: run window shell as administrator

set-executionpolicy unrestricted

Forth step : yarn global add @vue/cli

Result:

C:\Users\User>vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.15